# Removing a Vue custom filter on mouseover

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, vue.js, vuejs2

I would like to remove a truncate filter on mouseover using VueJS 2. Here is my filter in the template:

```
<div class="eng" @mouseover="showAll">{{ word.english | truncate }}</div>
```

And here is the filter itself:

```
filters: {
    truncate: function(value) {
      let length = 50;
      if (value.length <= length) {
        return value;
      } else {
        return value.substring(0, length) + '...';
      }
    }
 },
```

Is there a way to remove the filter on the mouseover event so that the div is not truncated anymore? Thanks!

Edit: The `showAll()` function is where I thought I would remove it. I tried a couple ways to remove the filter such as:

```
showAll(){
  console.log('being mousedover');
  this.truncate = false
},
```

and:

```
showAll(){
  console.log('being mousedover');
  !this.truncate
}
```

but this is where I am lost...

Comment: Does anything happen when you mouseover? Can you include the code for `showAll`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make `showAll` a Boolean data property and use `template` tags to determine which version of `word.english` to display via the `v-if` and `v-else` directives:

```
<div class="eng" @mouseover="showAll = true">
  <template v-if="showAll">{{ word.english }}</template>
  <template v-else>{{ word.english | truncate }}</template>
</div>
```

[Here's a working fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/nqhgpv5y/1/)

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest way to handle this is to set a boolean flag, and then filter a computed property based on the potential existence of the flag.  This allows you to cache the value and you only need a single element with one conditional watcher instead of two.

HTML

```
<div class="eng" @mouseover="showAll = true" @mouseout="showAll = false">
  {{getWord}}
</div>
```

JS

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            showAll: false,
            word: {}
        }
    },
    computed: {
        getWord: function () {
            if (this.showAll) return this.word.english

            let value = this.word.english;
            let length = 50;
            if (value.length <= length) {
                return value;
            } else {
                return value.substring(0, length) + '...';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution worked for me however, I neglected to mention that it is in a v-for loop. Is there any way to prevent the action happening to all of the divs and only be applied to the one I am hovering over?

Comment: @DavidL this is definitely less verbose and is a totally valid solution. But, I find that, in practice, being able to see potential DOM changes in a component's template is pretty helpful. Definitely a gray area. But in this case, I think being able to see the effects of the `showAll` variable in those four lines in the template is more readable overall than having to jump to a computed method's definition to see if the `showAll` variable is related and what it affects.

Comment: @lnamba would need to see how you're coding that. Post another question if you can't figure it out.

Comment: @thanksd that's of course a matter of personal preference.  i'll always lean towards debugging JS over manually inspecting a template and I'll always pick a solution (when reasonable) that utilizes less watchers, although both are absolutely valid approaches :)

Comment: @DavidL yeah totally preference. And I'll probably change my mind in a month :P

Comment: @DavidL thanks for your help! I am posting a new question when SO lets me in 90 minutes... I will post it here, but really great advice. Thanks!

Comment: @thanksd thanks for your help! I am posting a new question when SO lets me in 90 minutes... I will post it here, but really great advice. Thanks!

Comment: @lnamba happy to help :).  I agree with thanksd that it is definitely a new question since that would change the approach considerably.

Comment: Here is a link to my new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45198393/v-for-causing-actions-to-be-applied-to-all-divs

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
data(){
    return {
      shouldTruncate: true
    }
},
methods: {
    showAll() {
        this.shouldTruncate = false
    }
},
filters:{
    truncate(value) {
        let length = 50;
        if (value.length <= length || !this.shouldTruncate) {
            return value;
        }
        else {
            return value.substring(0, length) + '...';
        }
    }
}
```