# v-for causing actions to be applied to all divs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Previously I asked a question about removing a custom truncate filter in Vue. Please see the question here:

[Removing a Vue custom filter on mouseover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45196501/removing-a-vue-custom-filter-on-mouseover/45196804?noredirect=1#comment77361668_45196804)

However, I neglected to mention that I am using a v-for loop and when I hover over one div, I am noticing that all the divs in the loop are having the same action applied to them. I'm not sure how to target only the div that is being hovered over. Here is my template:

```
 <div id="tiles">
    <button class="tile" v-for="(word, index) in shuffled" @click="clickWord(word, index)" :title="word.english">
      <div class="pinyin">{{ word.pinyin }}</div>
      <div class="eng" @mouseover="showAll = true" @mouseout="showAll = false">
        <div v-if="showAll">{{ word.english }}</div>
        <div v-else>{{ word.english | truncate }}</div>
      </div>
    </button>
  </div>
```

And the data being returned:

```
  data(){
    return {
      currentIndex: 0,
      roundClear: false,
      clickedWord: '',
      matchFirstTry: true,
      showAll: false,
    }
  },
```

If you know Vue, I would be grateful for advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your example, `showAll` is being used for each of the buttons generated by the v-for to determine whether or not to show the complete text of the `word.english` value. This means that whenever the `mouseover` event of any the `.eng` class divs fires, the same `showAll` property is being set to true for every button.

---

I would replace the `showAll` Boolean value with a `showWordIndex` property initially set to `null`:

```
data() {
  showWordIndex: null,
},
```

And then in the template, set `showWordIndex` to the `index` of the word on the `mouseover` handler (and to `null` in the `mouseleave` handler):

```
<button v-for="(word, index) in shuffled" :key="index">
  <div class="pinyin">{{ word.pinyin }}</div>
  <div 
    class="eng" 
    @mouseover="showWordIndex = index" 
    @mouseout="showWordIndex = null" 
  >
    <div v-if="showWordIndex === index">{{ word.english }}</div>
    <div v-else>{{ word.english | truncate }}</div>
  </div>
</button>
```

[Here's a working fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/nqhgpv5y/2/)

---

Even better would be to make a new component to encapsulate the functionality and template of everything being rendered in the `v-for`, passing the properties of each `word` object to the child component as props.

This way, you would still use the `showAll` property like you are in your example, but you would define it in the child component's scope. So now the `showAll` property will only affect the instance of the component it's related to.

Below is an example of that:

```js
Vue.component('tile', {
  template: '#tile',
  props: ['pinyin', 'english'],
  data() {
    return { showAll: false };
  },
  filters: {
    truncate: function(value) {
      let length = 50;
      if (value.length <= length) {
        return value;
      } else {
        return value.substring(0, length) + '...';
      }
    }
  },
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      words: [
        {pinyin: 1, english: "really long string that will be cut off by the truncate function"},
        {pinyin: 2, english: "really long string that will be cut off by the truncate function"},
        {pinyin: 3, english: "really long string that will be cut off by the truncate function"},
        {pinyin: 4, english: "really long string that will be cut off by the truncate function"},
      ],
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.1/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <tile v-for="word, i in words" v-bind="word" :key="word"></tile>
</div>

<script id="tile" type="x-template">
  <button :title="english">
    <div class="pinyin">{{ pinyin }}</div>
    <div class="eng" @mouseover="showAll = true" @mouseout="showAll = false">
      <div v-if="showAll">{{ english }}</div>
      <div v-else>{{ english | truncate }}</div>
    </div>
  </button>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, you can't use a computed property (as I originally suggested in the answer of mine that you linked), since you need to be aware of the context that you are in.  That said, you CAN use a filter if you apply a `showAll` property to each individual instance.  If you declare this up front in your data model, the property will be reactive and you can toggle each item individually on mouseover and mouseout.

template:

```
<div id="app">
  <div id="tiles">
    <div class="tile" v-for="(word, index) in shuffled" :title="word.english">
      <div class="pinyin">{{ word.pinyin }}</div>
      <div class="eng" @mouseover="word.showAll = true" @mouseout="word.showAll = false">
        {{ word.english | truncate(word) }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
        return {
            shuffled: [
                { english: 'here', showAll: false}, 
                { english: 'are', showAll: false }, 
                { english: 'there', showAll: false },
                { english: 'words', showAll: false }
            ],
            currentIndex: 0,
            roundClear: false,
            clickedWord: '',
            matchFirstTry: true,
        }
    },
    filters: {
        truncate: function(value, word) {
            console.log(word)
            let length = 3;
            if (word.showAll || value.length <= length) return value;

            return value.substring(0, length) + '...';
        }
    },
})
```

See working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8wsLa6zr/1/)

The key is to apply `showAll` to each word instance and to then pass that word instance back to the filter so that we can check the value of the showAll property.  As long as you declare it up front, Vue's reactivity system handles the rest for you.

Note that in this example it isn't necessary to use two elements with a v-if/else.  A single element with a filter works perfectly.